# Excel: How to sum two different numbers in same cell?

Tags: excel, numbers, sum, formula

I have some info like below:

```
3/7
4/6
5/1
```

And I want a formula that will add them up to a total based on the numbers on either side of the slash.  So the result cell from the above would be: `12/14`.  Anyone know how I can do this?  Please let me know if this is not clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming data in A1:A3, you could enter this in A4:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)-1))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(A1:A3,1,FIND("/",A1:A3),0))
```

Comment: Nice, I have never seen SUMPRODUCT used in this way, nor have I seen the double minus used. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can explode the contents of the cell using the LEFT/RIGHT and FIND function, from there you can add them :)
Add two columns

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1))
```

Those should explode the strings into the numbers, then add them and merge them.